# React time duration input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, material-ui

I am new to react and I am working on a project. I want the user to input the time that he has spent on doing work. For example, the user can input 2:20 hours or 1:30 hours that he has spent on a task. I am using material UI and I have tried to use `TextField` with type=`time`. And it could work on desktop but it is rendered differently on mobile.

**This is how it is looking on the desktop. And this is still good.**

[image: This is how it is looking on desktop]

[image: this is how it looks on desktop]

But as it is an `time input field`, on mobile it is rendered as a clock. And this is not what i want. I want input as hours and minutes spend.

[image: rendered on mobile]

This might be because of browser renders `time input` in this way on mobiles.

So is there any way that I can render it on mobile the same as it is rendered on desktop or there is any other react package available that I can use for `time-duration` input? I have tried some packages from npm but those do not work as expected.

Comment: That’s how android chrome renders the controls for time input. There’s not much you can do about it, besides baking your own or finding a third party library (the latter which is off topic according to StackOverflow rules).